# Visual Studio 2015 bower broken

Tags: visual-studio, bower, visual-studio-2015

So I have Visual Studio 2015 RC1 Enterprise installed. In my web project under dependencies bower is showing an error complaining about a syntax error. There is no error that I can see in my file. It worked perfectly in older version of 2015 so not sure what is wrong.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "3.0.0"
    },
    "name": "MyProject",
    "private", true
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your syntax on the last line, where you have a comma instead of a colon.

Change `"private", true` to `"private": true`